# (Co)Variance on Lists different then on Stacks in Scala?

Tags: java, generics, scala, covariance

When I'm writing this code, I've got a Compile error in Scala

```
var s: Stack[_ <: Number] = new Stack[Integer]; 
s.push(new Integer(1)); //compile-error: type mismatch; found :Integer required: _$bqjyh where type _$bqjyh <: Number
s.push(null); //compile-error: type mismatch; found   : Null(null) required: _$2 where type _$2 <: Objects.Vehicle
```

This is equivalent to covariant collection in Java due the wildcard; it exact type in unknown, so we cannot added something to the stack.

But with lists I won't get the same error:

```
   var list: List[_ <: Number] = Nil;
   var intList : List[Integer] = new Integer(1) :: Nil;
   list = intList ; //no error
   list = new Float(2) :: vehicles;  //even float allowed
```

Now I can added even a `float`, but in fact I would believe the `list` is a `List` of `Integers`, so not `Floats` allowed.

1) Why is this allowed with lists, and not with Stacks? Is this due to the cons (::) operator?

2) What is the type of list? Is it dynamic?

3) Why is this allowed in Scala and not in Java?

4) Can I add something to the stack? (`null` is not working, in Java does because generic types only allows reference types)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`::` isn't a mutating operation. This means that `x :: xs` will return a List of type `List[ commonSupertypeOf[ typeOf[x], elementTypeOf[xs] ] ]` (this isn't actual scala code, but I hope my point comes across), but it will not change the type of `xs`. If `xs` has type `List[Float]` and `x` has type `Integer`, then the expression `x :: xs` will have type `List[Numeric]`, but the type of `xs` is still `List[Float]`, so nothing breaks.

`add` however is a mutating operation. `xs.add(x)` will add an `Integer` to a `Stack` whose type is `Stack<Float>`, which is clearly an error.

This explains why doing `x :: xs` is not dangerous. Now to explain why it typeckecks:

The singnature of `::` on a `List[A]` is:  `def :: [B >: A] (x: B) : List[B]`.

What this means is that for any types `A` and `B` where `B` is a supertype of `A`, `::` given a value of type `B` and a list of type `A` will produce a list of type `B`. So when you do some `someInteger :: someFloats`, the compiler infers that `B` is `Numeric` and `A` is `Float` and everything works.

In java terms that would be `<B supertypeOf A> List<B> prepend(B item)` except that `supertypeOf` isn't legal java.

Comment: So to summarize: Lists are immutable and :: creates a new list, so nothing breaks; this in contrast with Stacks. This is correct?

Comment: But this is legal Java? (so it's possible but not done?)
class List<A>{
 <B extends A> List<B> prepend(B item)
}

Comment: @j-verdurmen: Yes, that's legal java, but it's the wrong way around: `A` must extend `B` for it to make sense, not the other way around. The body of prepend would look something like this: `List<B> result = new LinkedList<B>(); result.add(item); result.addAll(this); return result;`. However this will only compile if `A extends B`, not if `B extends A`.

Answer (score 4):

The Scala language uses definition-site variance annotations, not use-site variance annotations.  Covariance for Lists is defined in the List trait, while Stacks are not defined as covariant.  In general, mutable collections *can't* be covariant, because that leads to type errors involving inserting new elements into the collection (which is a major problem with Java's covariant arrays.)

Comment: As with all of Scala's collections for which there are both immutable and mutable variants, the immutable forms are covariant and the mutable ones are invariant.